# UTF-8の文字列をC言語で表示したい

Tags: c, 文字コード

#### 実現したいこと

C言語でUTF-8の文字列をバイナリから出力したいです。
例えば「E3 81 82」が「あ」になりますので、配列「に0xE3, 0x81, 0x82, 0x00」と格納して、
printf()関数のような何かで出力させたいです。
実現方法を教えてください。
もしくはUTF-8のデータからShift JISのデータに変換する方法があればそちらでも構いません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

UTF-8のデータからShift JISのデータに変換する方法があればそちらをお願いいたします。

#### 該当のソースコード

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main()
{
    char  moji1[] = { 0xE3, 0x81, 0x82, 0x00 };
    char  moji2[] = "あ";    //Shift JIS (82 A0)

    printf("%s\n", moji1);
    printf("%s\n", moji2);

    return 0;
}
```

#### こちらでも

https://teratail.com/questions/1r7gfqf1t4at0h

Comment: Shift JISということは Windowsですか？ WSLで動かしてみては？

Comment: 環境情報として、OS の情報とターミナルの情報が欲しいです。質問文を [edit] して追記してみてください。

Comment: 使っているOS, コンパイラ, IDE/エディタ, ツールセット といったものの種類や版数を示して、現在何のために何をしようとして何処が問題/課題になっているのかなどの情報を追記してください。それらの内容によっては取り得る手段が変わったり、実際には問題では無かったりすることが考えられます。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)

Comment: 質問に記載されたマルチポスト先でこちらの記事 [【C言語】UTF8 <-> SJIS 変換（VisualStudio2017）](https://namco.hatenablog.jp/entry/2019/01/06/122150) を参考に自己解決とのこと。

Answer (score 1):

文字コード変換のC言語ライブラリですと libiconv が該当するんじゃないでしょうか。

[libiconv - GNU Project - Free Software Foundation (FSF)](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/)

Answer (score 1):

以下のコードで「あ」が表示されるようになります。
この変更をした場合、shift-jisが文字化けするようになりますが。

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //←追加

int main(){
    system("chcp 65001"); //←追加
    char  moji1[] = { 0xE3, 0x81, 0x82, 0x00 };
    char  moji2[] = "あ";    //Shift JIS (82 A0)

    printf("%s\n", moji1);
    printf("%s\n", moji2);

    return 0;
}
```